# How to extract non-empty elements from python for number list

Tags: python, list, flatten

I currently have a list that looks like this:

```
[
    [0], [2], [4], [6], [7], [9], [20], [24],
    [], [26], [], [27], [], [], [], [],
    [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [],
    [], []
]
```

How can I transform it to look like `[0, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 20, 24, 26, 27]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a list comprehension:

```
out = [l[0] for l in list1 if len(l) > 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `list1` the input list, use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
from itertools import chain

out = list(chain.from_iterable(list1))
```

output: `[0, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 20, 24, 26, 27]`